# Where is the UDID stored on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios

Where on the iPhone is information regarding the phone's UDID, IMEI, serial number, etc. stored? Are they somewhere in the filesystem, or are they off of the hard drive and stored somewhere else instead?

My question is not how I can access the UDID in an app that I am writing for the iPhone, but rather I want to know how and/or where iOS stores this information in the filesystem.

Comment: Sounds like you want to view a "tear down" video, which shows you all the different chips inside, and explains what they are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the MAC address of a network device the UDID is hard coded into the iPhone/iPad hardware itself.

Without jailbreaking it can't be changed. However if you want to [jailbreak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18534766/can-we-change-the-udid-on-my-iphone-ipad) your phone it is possible to fake the UDID, kind of like MAC address spoofing (or so it seems).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Do you have any idea what specific piece of hardware stores this information?

Comment: Sorry no. The Cydia/Jailbreaking people might have that info.